# Do not park on the parking lane

Tags: driving

How come Alberta's driver's guide says
on a roadway outside an urban area, "[do
not park on the parking lane](https://www.alberta.ca/parking.aspx?)"? Isn't such a lane used for parking? Thank you!

"On a roadway outside an urban area, do not park:

on the roadway, parking lane or shoulder of a primary highway except where:

- your vehicle is incapable of moving under its own power,
- an emergency arises, or
- it is permitted by law"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading those clauses, you can see that you can park in an emergency. You can park with your vehicle dies and you can't move it. You can park if it is specifically allowed (maybe a sign saying "unrestricted parking allowed here").
Otherwise, you may park on a parking lane (or roadway, or shoulder) but subject to conditions also listed: "unless there is a clear passage for other motor vehicles, and your vehicle can be seen for 60 metres (200 feet) along the roadway in both directions".

Regardless of the name of the piece of road, you *are* allowed to park there but only *if* your car is clearly visible, and there is room to get around you.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your detailed explanations!

Comment: Thank you so very much for your detailed explanations!